# How to hit parameterized url in Apache Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

This is my test URL " **http://appr.seconddemo.org/hitssurveys/survey?uid=113&offerid=311&subid=subvalues&offr_id={Email}** "

I want to hit the url 1500 times per second , and want to change the "{Email}" with real value in each iteration.

How it's possible please give me a step by step guide.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you need to pass the emails from the external file, the most efficient way that we are using in software testing companies is to pass the variable from .csv or .txt files using 'CSV Data Set Config' element of the JMeter.

Please find the steps that you need to follow:

- Add a 'CSV Data Set Config' element from 'Config Element' by right-clicking the thread group

  - Set Filename field with complete path to your .csv or .txt file that contains your emails
  - Set Variable field as 'Email' [This variable name should be same as you set in your url request]
  - Ignore first line to False
  - Set other fields as per your requirement[image]
- Now add HTTP Sampler in your Thread Group and set the Protocol, Server Name, Method & Path as instructed in the screenshot: [image]

  - Create .csv or .txt file and add all emails separated by new line:
    [image]

Hope this answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSV Data Set Config. Put all your email credentials in the CSV file and make sure you have put this CSV file in your JMeter /bin directory.

Add a CSV dataset config in your test plan. Your CSV dataset config should be like:

[image]

Now in your thread group, define the number of threads you want to execute and then in your sampler put the path as follows:

```
 http://appr.seconddemo.org/hitssurveys/survey?uid=113&offerid=311&subid=subvalues&offr_id=${Email}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply . Can you please share the structure of the csv file, I am a beginner so it will be helpful for me . You can see there is a "email" at end of the url . I want to change that email. that's it

Comment: You can use a text file also.Each email will reside on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where do your emails live there are following options:

1. If they are in a text file, each email on a new line you can use [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) like:
2. If they are in a database you can use [JDBC PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PreProcessor) to fetch the data from the database table column and put your request under [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)
3. If you need to provide just some random characters you can use [__RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function.

More information: [JMeter Parameterization - The Complete Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-parameterization-the-complete-guide)